# Implement HighChart In Android Using WebView

Tags: android, webview, highcharts

I don't know why Webview still displayed tooltip text after it finished. In detail, This is the test case:

step 1: I press any column and simultaneously the chart display tooltip about column's info, right. But, In addition, the "copy" of tooltip is displayed beside the original one. I don't know why and how the "copy" existed.

step 2: Look at Highchart. After tooltip down, the "copy" did not disappear. why not ?

(I using Android OS version 2.2.1)
Thank you so much!

Comment: @Gopinagh.R: Could you give me some ideas?

Comment: Can you post your code snippet ?